# make interactive text area on top of canvas

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I want to draw Interactive text area on canvas .Normaly , using id and classes we can change div css property but with canvas how can i achieve same functionality .

i want to write text on top of  canvas which should change on change event of some text area.i wish to use menu bar to achieve functionality like change font-color,font-size,font-family etc .

with div id and class i can change css but on canvas how can i achieve this?? please suggest ?[image]

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of others like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823328/html5-edit-text-on-the-canvas

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi inside canvas?

Comment: the text inside canvas is a picture, you can't edit it. did you research before asking the question? or maybe I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @ile The onscreen end result of any text editor is a picture on a display - there just a bunch of code keeping track of characters, cursor position, font size etc and drawing the results.  No reason why you can't do that with canvas.

Comment: @dc5 of course you could manipulate the pixels of the drawn text, what I mean is you can't access the text directly as an object. This seemed to be what the question was about.

Comment: Have a look at this <http://oldstatic.travisberry.com/demos/canvas-text-demo/index.html>

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi that is erasing and redrawing, not editing the existing one

Comment: @ile - I see what you are saying.  I'm not entirely sure what the OP is after either.

Answer (score 0):

You control text XY position in the same command that draws text: `context.fillText("test",20,25);`

You control font size and font family like this: `context.font="14pt Verdana".`

You control text color using the fill like this:  `context.fillStyle="gold".`

You control opacity like this: `context.globalAlpha=.80`.  (0.00=invisible, 1.00=fully opaque).

You control text rotation using a transform like this:

```
context.save();
context.rotate(30*Math.PI/180);
context.fillText("Test",20,20);
context.restore();
```

You would have to control these using your own custom coding (some easy, some moderate):

- Line spacing,
- Character spacing,
- Text Alignment,
- Underlining,
- Text on path (curved text)
- Right to left orientation

There is no capability to italicize (unless the font has italicized characters).