# Chart.js is it possible to style the labels?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using the [chart.js](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js) to display some long line charts with the following labels:

```
labels : ["2014","sem I","sem II","sem III","sem IV","2015","sem I","sem II","sem III","sem IV","2016","sem I","sem II","sem III","sem IV",]
```

All I want to know is if its possible to make only the years in **bold** for a better readability?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580585/7186739

Comment: Hello from 2021, looks like ChartJS added a way to add your own html legend via plugin: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.6.0/samples/legend/html.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/):

```
// String - Scale label font weight style
scaleFontStyle: "normal",
```

Comment: I just need the years in bold or other color to differentiate from others

Comment: I don't think the library has that option available.

Comment: I know I'm looking for a way to "extend" or "hack" the code.

Comment: They use HTML5 canvas element to draw the charts, you could try edit the text in the canvas (it's not an easy task). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823328/html5-edit-text-on-the-canvas