# How can I change the font (family) for the labels in Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js2

I want to change the font to something snazzier in my Chart.JS horizontal bar chart. I've tried the following, but none of it works:

```
var optionsBar = {
    . . .
    //fontFamily: "'Candara', 'Calibri', 'Courier', 'serif'"
    //bodyFontFamily: "'Candara', 'Calibri', 'Courier', 'serif'"
    //bodyFontFamily: "'Candara'"
    label: {
        font: {
            family: "Georgia"
        }
    }
};
```

I also read that this would work:

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFont = "Georgia"
```

...but where would this code go, and how exactly should it look? I tried this:

```
priceBarChart.defaults.global.defaultFont = "Georgia";
```

...but also to no good effet.

For the full picture/context, here is all the code that makes up this chart:

HTML

```
<div class="chart">
    <canvas id="top10ItemsChart" class="pie"></canvas>
    <div id="pie_legend"></div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
    var ctxBarChart = 
$("#priceComplianceBarChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var barChartData = {
        labels: ["Bix Produce", "Capitol City", "Charlies Portland", 
"Costa Fruit and Produce", "Get Fresh Sales",
"Loffredo East", "Loffredo West", "Paragon", "Piazza Produce"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Price Compliant",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,0.5)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(34,139,34,1)",
                data: [17724, 5565, 3806, 5925, 5721, 6635, 14080, 9027, 
25553]
            },
            {
                label: "Non-Compliant",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)",
                hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)",
                data: [170, 10, 180, 140, 30, 10, 50, 100, 10]
            }
        ]
    }

    var optionsBar = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }]
        },
        //fontFamily: "'Candara', 'Calibri', 'Courier', 'serif'"
        //bodyFontFamily: "'Candara', 'Calibri', 'Courier', 'serif'"
        //bodyFontFamily: "'Candara'"
        //Chart.defaults.global.defaultFont = where does this go?
        label: {
            font: {
                family: "Georgia"
            }
        }
    };

    var priceBarChart = new Chart(ctxBarChart, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: barChartData,
        options: optionsBar
    });
    //priceBarChart.defaults.global.defaultFont = "Georgia";
```

I even tried this:

CSS

```
.candaraFont13 {
    font-family:"Candara, Georgia, serif";
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="graph_container candaraFont13">
    <canvas id="priceComplianceBarChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

...but I reckon the canvas drawing takes care of the font appearance, as adding this made no difference.

### UPDATE

I tried this and it completely broke it:

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
    defaultFontFamily: "Georgia"
}
```

### UPDATE 2

As Matthew intimated, this worked (before any of the chart-specific script):

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Georgia";
```

Comment: Sorry, I retired from programming, and have no access to that old code.

Comment: Working Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580585/7186739

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should be useful: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/. It says "There are 4 special global settings that can change all of the fonts on the chart. These options are in `Chart.defaults.global`".

You'll need to change `defaultFontFamily` for the font. And `defaultFontColor`, `defaultFontSize`, and `defaultFontStyle` for color, size, etc.

Comment: Where? I made a guess at it by using my chart name to replace "Chart" but that didn't work.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to change `Chart` to your chart name. I notice that you have `Chart.defaults.global.defaultFont = "Georgia"`. The line should work if it is `Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Georgia"`.

Comment: You can add a font family to the ...options: { legend: { labels: { fontFamily: 'FontYouWant' } },...}

Here is a link: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Answer (score 11):

Change font size, color, family and weight using chart.js

```
scales: {
        yAxes: [{ticks: {fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif", fontColor: '#000', fontStyle: '500'}}],
        xAxes: [{ticks: {fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif", fontColor: '#000', fontStyle: '500'}}]
        }
```

**See the full code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Chart.js</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="js/utils.js"></script>
        <style>
            canvas {
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -ms-user-select: none;
                font-weight:700;  
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width:70%;">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        <script>
            var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            var color = Chart.helpers.color;
            var barChartData = {
                labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
                datasets: [{
                        label: 'Completed',
                        // Green
                        backgroundColor: '#4caf50',
                        borderColor: '#4caf50',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55
                        ]
                    }, {
                        label: 'Created',
                        // Blue
                        backgroundColor: '#1976d2',
                        borderColor: '#1976d2',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        data: [
                            10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60
                        ]
                    }]

            };

            window.onload = function () {
                var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: barChartData,
                    options: {
                        responsive: true,
                        legend: {
                            position: 'top',
                            onClick: null
                        },

                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: '',
                            fontSize: 20
                        },
                        scales: {
                            yAxes: [{ticks: {fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif", fontColor: '#000', fontStyle: '500'}}],
                            xAxes: [{ticks: {fontSize: 12, fontFamily: "'Roboto', sans-serif", fontColor: '#000', fontStyle: '500'}}]
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you wanted to add the font-family to the chart object then you can add it in the options object.

```
options: {
  legend: {
    labels: { 
      fontFamily: 'YourFont'
    }
  }...}
```

Here is a link to the docs: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Answer (score 1):

You named the chart priceBarChart in the following part of your code:

```
var priceBarChart = new Chart(ctxBarChart, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: barChartData,
  options: optionsBar
})
```

Which means that `priceBarChart.defaults.global.defaultFont = 'Georgia'` will 'dive' into the variable priceBarChart, go into its default properties, change one of its global properties and that one is defaultFont, exactly what you want.

But when you apply this code, you basically create the chart with the wrong font and then change it again, which is a bit ugly. What you need to do is tell the chart what the font is beforehand.

You do this by merging your font declaration with the rest of the options, just like how you did it with your variables `barChartData` and `optionsBar`.

After you've created `barChartData` and `optionsBar`, create another variable with the name, let's say, `defaultOptions`, like so:

```
var defaultOptions = {
    global: {
        defaultFont: 'Georgia'
    }
}
```

You can see that it has the same structure. You go into the global options, and change its defaultFont property. Now you need to apply it to the created chart at the moment it is created, like so:

```
var priceBarChart = new Chart(ctxBarChart, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: barChartData,
  options: optionsBar,
  defaults: defaultOptions //This part has been added
})
```

This method of overwriting options is what is being used in almost every JavaScript plugin. When you create a `new` instance, the plugin copies an object that contains objects that contain objects and so forth. But these objects can be modified with additional options, like `barChartData`, `optionsBar` and `defaultOptions`.

I hope this helps!