# Chart Js - Bar Chart- How to make the first line of Label BOLD?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, bar-chart, chartjs-2.6.0

```
var horizontalBarChart = new Chart(horizontalBarChartCanvas, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
                labels: [["Company Brand A", "Brand A"], "Company Brand B", "Company Brand C", "Company Brand D", "Company Brand E", "Company Brand F", "Company Brand G"],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [5000, 12000, 3000, 8000, 10000, 4000, 14000],
                    backgroundColor: ["#01d283", "#01d283", "#01d283", "#01d283", "#01d283", "#01d283", "#01d283"],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                tooltips: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                    position: 'bottom',
                    fullWidth: true,
                },
                scales: {
                    pointLabels: {
                        fontStyle: "bold",
                    },
                    yAxes: [{
                        barPercentage: 0.50,
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false,
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: '#004c7f',
                            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false,
                            tickMarkLength: 5,
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: '#004c7f',
                            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                            weight: "bold"
                        },
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: false,
                            fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                            fontColor: '#004c7f',
                            labelString: 'Scale Label'
                        },
                    }],
                },
            }
        });
```

I am using chart.js, and unable to make the first line of label BOLD!

Can anyone suggest how?

Please review my code and attachment.

*P.S the first line bold shown in the attached made in photoshop.*

*I've already tried this, but the below code is not working*

```
scales: {
     pointLabels: {
          fontStyle: "bold",
     },
}
```

[Chart JS Label - How to BOLD?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Pqa.png)

Comment: Can you a fiddle of what you have tried, that will be helpful

Comment: the code is in a project, cannot fiddle!

Comment: without your functional sample, it will be difficult ot help you

Comment: Duplicate? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221425/chart-js-make-part-of-labels-bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221425/chart-js-make-part-of-labels-bold)

Comment: @RobMoll The question / answer you have suggested seems to be duplicate, but both the codes are different. And we have already tried your referred link, and it didnt work. Please Suggest!