# Chart js - Customize chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to edit a chart but i can't.
I want to change the canvas height to a fix height. The chart start always with 1156px X 867. And i need to change also the heigh of each bar.

So, how can i change the size of canvas and how can i change the height of each bar.
I have this code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart");
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: 'horizontalBar',
              data: {
                  labels: data['labels'],
                  datasets: [{
                      label: '# of Votes',
                      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                      backgroundColor: [
                          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                      ],
                      borderColor: [
                          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 1
                  }]
              },
              options: {
                  scales: {
                      yAxes: [{
                          ticks: {
                              beginAtZero:true
                          }
                      }]
                  }
              }
          });
```

html:

```
<canvas id="chartMentes" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: May be this one will useful for you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580585/7186739

Answer (score 0):

> **How can I change the size of canvas?**

Usually, ChartJS displays chart in a responsive manner, meaning it won't take canvas­*'s* width and height *(set by user)* into consideration.

To get around this, you need to set `responsive` property to `false` in your chart options, like so ...

```
options: {
  responsive: false,
  ...
}
```

Now, you could set canvas­*'s* width and height as per your requirement.

```
<canvas id="chartMentes" width="400" height="800"></canvas>
```

> **How can I change the height of each bar?**

You can change the height of each bar by setting the `barThickness` property accordingly for y-axis in the chart options, like so ...

```
options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
            barThickness: 10,  //set that suits the best
            ...
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("chartMentes").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
             'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: [
             'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
              'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
              'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
              'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                barThickness: 10,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chartMentes" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```