# Chart.js displays the label in a weird font in IE8

Tags: fonts, chart.js

How can I find the font used in [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)?

I have tried to look in the documentation and see a family of fonts, but I am not sure which font is exactly used.

Comment: [This question might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603447/how-can-i-change-the-font-family-for-the-labels-in-chart-js) to help you set default fonts.

Answer (score 0):

The `fontFamily` config option is available for different components, and you can use that to change the font to something you know works in IE.

Based on the documentation, it seems like the default font is `"'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif"`.

I've created a JSFiddle that demonstrates changing the font for the three components mentioned below: https://jsfiddle.net/nva5hwLp/

### Ticks

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        fontFamily: 'Times New Roman'
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

See the [Axes Labeling documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html) for more information and font styling options. It seems like the documentation currently suggests placing the `fontFamily` config under a key called `scaleLabel`, however it only works if you put it under the `ticks` section.

### Legend

```
options: {
  legend: {
    labels: {
      fontFamily: 'Times New Roman'
    }
  }
}
```

See the [Fonts documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html) for more information. Currently, the documentation says to use `defaultFontFamily`, however it seems to only work when you use `fontFamily`.

### Title

```
options: {
  title: {
    text: 'something',
    display: true,
    fontFamily: 'Times New Roman'
  }
}
```

See the [Title config documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html) for more information.