# Chart Js reduce text size for label on X axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js (http://www.chartjs.org/) and it's working fine, but I have too big X labels also with 45 degrees orientation (is auto adjusting).
I would like to reduce the size of that text, is it possible to do only for X axis?
thanks

Comment: You could use `labels: fontSize` property https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48580585/7186739

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in the [ticks.fontSize](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) configuration you can do it only for the x-axis. For example

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 8
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks, just added this
 xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          fontSize: 8
        }
      }] and i resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For version 3.5.1 it's:

options.scales.x.ticks.font.size = $FONT_SIZE